# targeting a span within a div to Scrape from google search results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a scraper with python, and i cant target a span element that is within multiple div. 
The URL are Google search results so lets take an example of a parking :

[image]

> https://www.google.com/search?q=Thomas+Muntzer+Strasse+122+parking+Gamstadt

I would like to target the name of this parking in the results page.(highlighted element on my screenshot)

```
def getPropNames(soup):
    result = soup.findAll('div', class_="BNeawe deIvCb AP7Wnd" )
    for elm in result:
        names.append(elm.text)
```

I used this function i created before but the problem was that it takes multiple results on the webpage and flood my excel then when i save it with unwanted results, how can i target specifically a span within multiple div and if there are no id ?

Thanks in advance if you need more informations to solve my issue let me know ! :)

Comment: share either the link or the html, otherwise we can't help you

Comment: Oh yes sorry i forgot

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to get span element.find the parent `div` element and then use `find_next('span')`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
resspons=requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=Thomas+Muntzer+Strasse+122+parking+Gamstadt",headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(resspons.text,'html.parser')
print(soup.find('div',class_='SPZz6b').find_next('span').text)
```

**Output**:

```
AirPark Erfurt airport parking Jaritz & Büttner GbR
```

---

**UPDATE**:

```
url_list=['url1','url2']
names=[]
hdr={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
for url in url_list:
    req = requests.get(url, headers=hdr)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    try:
        names.append(soup.find('div', class_='SPZz6b').find_next('span').text)
    except:
        names.append("None")

print(names)
```

Comment: How do i do if i dont have a single url but a list of urls ?

Comment: Use for loop and iterate your urls.

Comment: thats what i did but 
when i try to launch it with this i get back an error : 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: for url in url_list:   
        req = Request(url, headers=hdr)
        page = urlopen(req)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        yield soup
    
def getPropNames(soup):
    result = soup.find('div',class_='SPZz6b').find_next('span').text
    for elm in result:
        names.append(elm.text)

Comment: This is because your search class name is not present for each url?

Comment: Oh ok i see how can i give instruction to fill in a blank in this case ?

Comment: @KyrianBourgi : first of all this will not work ` for elm in result: names.append(elm.text)` because you are fetching single element in result `result = soup.find('div',class_='SPZz6b').find_next('span').text`

Comment: @KyrianBourgi : use try except block.Check my Updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to visually grab `CSS` selectors from the page. I created [GIF](https://giphy.com/gifs/css-stackoverflow-selector-MRHV92xMI9DhdvxVcU) to demonstrate how to do it using your example.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
    "Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}
# could be replaced with actual URLs
queries = ['Thomas Muntzer Strasse 122 parking Gamstadt', 'P9 Terminal 2 Parking - Frankfurt Airport', 'london heathrow parking terminal 5']

for query in queries:
    html = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={query}', headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    try:
        address = soup.select_one('.hNKfZe span').text
    except:
        address = None
    print(address)

# output:
'''
AirPark Erfurt airport parking Jaritz & Büttner GbR
P9 Terminal 2 Parking - Frankfurt Airport
Heathrow POD Parking Terminal 5
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Search Engine Resutls API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

Essentially, the main difference is that you have ready data on which you need to iterate and pick the ones you need, rather than making everything from scratch.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

queries = ['Thomas Muntzer Strasse 122 parking Gamstadt',
           'P9 Terminal 2 Parking - Frankfurt Airport',
           'london heathrow parking terminal 5']

for query in queries:
    params = {
      "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
      "engine": "google",
      "q": query,
      "google_domain": "google.com",
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    try:
        answer = results['knowledge_graph']['title']
    except:
        answer = None
    print(answer)

# output:
'''
AirPark Erfurt airport parking Jaritz & Büttner GbR
P9 Terminal 2 Parking - Frankfurt Airport
Heathrow POD Parking Terminal 5
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.